# Delay JavaScript XX pixels from bottom of viewport

Tags: javascript, function, delay, viewport

I've seen a couple answers on how to delay the animation in CSS, but I was hoping to do it in Javascript.

I have an animation that activates as soon as the page loads. The website is a single page and I want the animation to activate when clients scroll to that section. I heard that you could do this by activating the animation X pixels from the bottom of the viewport.

Thanks

Comment: checkout http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/ or http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrollorama/. I think this is exactly what your are looking for

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4Za7v/) what you're looking for? In that example animation is based on the anchor element, but that's quite easy to change - for example, to be based on scrolling for 50% of the page's height.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little overkill but it should give you all the concepts you could want for what you're trying to achieve.

Basically, you test that the point you want to start your animation from is inside the rectangle of the screen, and use a flag to prevent the animation repeating itself for each scroll after you're in the region.

```
// teach JavaScript about coördinates
function CoOrdinate(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
CoOrdinate.prototype.inside = function (A, D) {
    if (this.x < A.x || D.x < this.x) return false;
    if (this.y < A.y || D.y < this.y) return false;
    return true;
}
// write a factory for the flag + action test
function actionFactory(hotspot, action) {
    var flag_done = false,
        test = function (topleft, bottomright) {
            if (flag_done) return; // cancel if we've done it before
            if (hotspot.inside(topleft, bottomright)) {
                flag_done = true;
                action();
            }
        };
    return test;
}
// create your action with the factory
var someAction = actionFactory(
        new CoOrdinate(0, 100), // the coördinate to be in the screen
        function () {console.log('foo')} // pass animation invocation here
    );
// so far none of this is getting invoked, so
// make the stuff all work when the page is scrolled
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    var x = window.pageXOffset,
        y = window.pageYOffset,
        h = window.screen.availHeight,
        w = window.screen.availWidth;
    someAction(
        new CoOrdinate(x    , y    ),
        new CoOrdinate(x + w, y + h)
    );
});
```

The above example just logs `"foo"` if the coördinate `[0, 100]` is in the screen.